# MariaDB: Duplicate entry for key on OPTIMIZE with no duplications

Tags: mysql, index, innodb, mariadb

There is a table named `contracts` with following structure:

```
MariaDB [db_name]> DESCRIBE `contracts`;
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name                        | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| number                      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| service_name                | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| begin_date                  | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| end_date                    | date         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| main_contract               | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| status                      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| uuid                        | varchar(36)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| database_id                 | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| abonent_uuid                | varchar(36)  | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| deleted                     | tinyint(1)   | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| active                      | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| payment_condition_name      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| payment_condition_form_type | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| gas                         | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | 0       |                |
| service_uuid                | varchar(36)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| document_type               | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| document_id                 | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| document_status             | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| signed                      | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0       |                |
| saved                       | tinyint(1)   | YES  | MUL | 0       |                |
| organization_code           | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
23 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

There is a unique composite index on `abonent_uuid` and `uuid`:

```
MariaDB [db_name]> SHOW INDEX FROM `contracts`;
+-----------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name                   | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| contracts |          0 | PRIMARY                    |            1 | id           | A         |      384633 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| contracts |          0 | index_contr_on_abon_uuid   |            1 | abonent_uuid | A         |      384633 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| contracts |          0 | index_contr_on_abon_uuid   |            2 | uuid         | A         |      384633 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| contracts |          1 | index_contracts_on_deleted |            1 | deleted      | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| contracts |          1 | index_contracts_on_saved   |            1 | saved        | A         |           2 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+----------------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

When I try to make mysqlcheck or OPTIMIZE (mysqlcheck -u root -p -o `db_name` contracts) on this table, I got this error:

```
db_name.contracts
note     : Table does not support optimize, doing recreate + analyze instead
error    : Duplicate entry '5661d82c-70d1-b019-3200-ca61e3f72e46-b9073669-4c3d-a089-6c2f-ddc' for key 'index_contr_on_abon_uuid'
status   : Operation failed
```

So we've got the following conflicting uuids:

```
5661d82c-70d1-b019-3200-ca61e3f7
2e46-b9073669-4c3d-a089-6c2f-ddc
```

Or only parts of them, full uuids are 36-bytes length. I don't know why MariaDB is cropping them. Indexes were created using this query:

```
ALTER TABLE `contracts` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `index_contr_on_abon_uuid` (`abonent_uuid`, `uuid`);
```

Also I've tried this (same result):

```
DROP INDEX `index_contr_on_abon_uuid` ON `contracts`;
ALTER TABLE `contracts` ADD UNIQUE INDEX `index_contr_on_abon_uuid` (`abonent_uuid`(36), `uuid`(36));
```

But there are NO non-unique records in the table (even if we crop uuids):

```
MariaDB [db_name]>   SELECT `abonent_uuid`, `uuid`
  ->   FROM `contracts`
  ->   GROUP BY SUBSTRING(`abonent_uuid`, 1, 32), SUBSTRING(`uuid`, 1, 32)
  ->   HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
Empty set (8.36 sec)
```

This error vanishes sometimes, but sometimes appears again sporadically. There were NO operations produced on this table during my experiments.

Hence, the **questions**: WHY does this error emerge? HOW can I fix it?

*P.S.*

Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)

mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.38-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2

ENGINE=InnoDB;

Comment: Did you mean to define UUID columns as `VARBINARY` may be? I suspect you're confusing binary UUID values with their character representations somewhere.

Comment: Explain where your UUIDs come from.  `2e46-b9073669-4c3d-a089-6c2f-ddc` is not a valid format, and it is probably truncated.

Comment: @RickJames, UUID is truncated in the INDEX. Original UUIDs in table records are full 36 characters (as expected). As you can see in the question above I've tried creating index, specifying the length of index field explicitly, but this composite index still remains 32+32 char long. Furthermore, there are no duplicates even with truncated UUIDs, which I proved by making SELECT query using GROUP BY with SUBSTRING function.

Comment: @mustaccio, UUIDs are defined as varchar(36), as you can see in my DESCRIBE query.

Comment: Change the `SELECT` to use `GROUP BY abonent_uuid, SUBSTRING(uuid, 1, 27)` -- I think you will then find the dup.

Comment: MariaDB [db_name]> SELECT `abonent_uuid`, `uuid`
FROM `contracts`
GROUP BY `abonent_uuid`, SUBSTRING(`uuid`, 1, 27)
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
Empty set (8.73 sec)
@RickJames, why 27, by the way?

Comment: @ProlifOvar - the pair of "conflicting uuids" looked strange.  So, I was guessing that the break between the uuids was not what you had guessed.  I'm guessing that the "Duplicate entry '...'" message is truncated to 64 chars.

Answer (score 0):

"Normal" UUIDs are 36 characters (including 4 dashes), not 32.  Fix that, and your dup key *may* go away.

Comment: This doesn't explain the problem.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ - This may not explain the problem, but it points out that the OP has a programming error(s).